# "to be of" vs "to be"

Tags: differences, meaning-in-context

> [Finally, Marshall pointed to the judge's oath ... Part of the core of this reasoning is found in the following statements from the decision: [(source, around fifteen lines above the heading Criticism)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marbury_v._Madison#The_decision)
>
> > ...
> > So, if a law [e.g., a statute or treaty] be in opposition to the Constitution, if both the law and the Constitution apply to a particular case, so that the Court must either decide that case conformably to the law, disregarding the Constitution, or conformably to the Constitution, disregarding the law, the Court must determine which of these conflicting rules governs the case. This is ♦ **of** the very essence of judicial duty. If, then, the Courts are to regard the Constitution, and the Constitution is superior to any ordinary act of the Legislature, the Constitution, and not such ordinary act, must govern the case to which they both apply.

Would someone please explain the preposition *of*?

Is the word *part* missing at the lozenge?

What would change or differ without *of*?

I'm asking about English and not about law.

Comment: *Of the essence* is an English idiom.

Comment: This is offtopic because it is a trivial matter of General Reference.  It is also Too Broad to ask us to teach you about the preposition *of*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "X is of the essence of Y" is an English idiom, connoting that X is in accordance with, or follows from the most crucial aspects of Y. (It may seem as if I have swapped X and Y here --- I have not. Think about this very carefully. The essence of Y is what X follows.)

The use of "very" merely serves to strengthen this statement.

What is being said here is that it follows from *a very core aspect of judicial duty* that the court must determine which of these conflicting rules governs the case.

---

I should note that the function that the **of** serves here can be explained as follows:

- "This is the essence of judicial duty" implies that *determining which of the conflicting rules governs the case* is **the** essence, that this job is absolutely and totally the most important and characterizing aspect of judicial duty.
- "This is of the essence of judicial duty" implies that *determining which of the conflicting rules governs the case* is **part of** the essence. It is essential, but it is not all that is essential.

So the striking difference here is that *this is of the essence of judicial duty* is not exclusive of other, perhaps essential, parts of judicial duty.